# Accessing array element in powershell - ignores [ ] indexers

Tags: html, arrays, string, powershell

I have a simple powershell script that sends mail after it finishes running

I have always used [] to access array elements without any problem

```
$isInstalled = "Yes No Yes" etc
$isInstalled[0] = "Yes"
```

The problem appears when trying to access the elements from within a string [html body]

Within the html body it only reads the array object and displays the [] as characters,
so it goes like this:

```
return "<td class='tg-yw4l'>$isInstalled[0]</td>"

Write-Host CallFunctionX
<td class='tg-yw4l'> Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No[0]</td>
```

results in `Yes No Yes[0]`
instead of `Yes`.

How can I tell powershell to take the indexer as well into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to change. declare the array properly:

```
$isInstalled = "Yes", "No", "Yes"
```

And use the correct way of interpolating the variable in format `$($var[index])`

```
return "<td class='tg-yw4l'>$($isInstalled[0])</td>"
```

Comment: The array is declared as such: [string[]]$isInstalled = "" And a loop adds something like this: $isInstalled += "No"

Comment: Tried your answer - the first part is unnecessary but the second part works...thanks!